Debian 12 Installer WiFi not recognised on Beelink Mini S12
WiFi adapter is not detected on my Beelink Mini S12 during Debian 12 installation. It does work with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS installer. I don't want to use a USB dongle or Ethernet during installation. What are my options?

If you installed from the minimal installer and without an alternative internet connection then drivers/firmware for your specific WiFi devices weren't installed. Either use the full installer or use an alternative internet connection (e.g. USB tethering) and fully update your system.
